# Convert pdf files to raw text in new directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pypdf, pdftotext

**Here is what I'm trying:**

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

import re
import config
import sys
import os

with open(config.ENCRYPTED_FILE_PATH, mode='rb') as f:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
        if reader.isEncrypted:
            reader.decrypt('Password123')
            print(f"Number of page: {reader.getNumPages()}")

            for i in range(reader.numPages):
                output = PdfFileWriter()
                output.addPage(reader.getPage(i))                
                with open("./pdfs/document-page%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
                    output.write(outputStream)
                    print(outputStream)

                    for page in output.pages: # failing here
                        print page.extractText() # failing here
```

The entire program is decrypting a large pdf file from one location, and splitting into a separate pdf file per page in new directory -- this is working fine. **However, after this I would like to convert each page to a raw `.txt` file in a new directory. *i.e.* `/txt_versions/`** *(for which I'll use later)*

*Ideally, I can use my current imports, i.e. PyPDF2 without importing/installing more modules/. Any thoughts?*

Comment: How is it failing? Is is not giving an output for the print statement? [PYPDF2 and Other PDF parsers aren't as robust as they seem](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/437) I usually dump the raw text into a list and then do what I need to do with the text

Answer (score 0):

You have not described how the last two lines are failing, but extract text does not function well on some PDFs:

[def extractText(self):](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/d7b8d3e0f471530267827511cdffaa2ab48bc1ad/PyPDF2/pdf.py#L2645)

"""
        Locate all text drawing commands, in the order they are provided in the
        content stream, and extract the text.  This works well for some PDF
        files, but poorly for others, depending on the generator used.  This will
        be refined in the future.  Do not rely on the order of text coming out of
        this function, as it will change if this function is made more
        sophisticated.
        :return: a unicode string object.
        """

One thing to do is to see if there is text in your pdf. Just because you can see words doesn't mean they have been OCR'd or otherwise encoded in the file as text. Attempt to highlight the text in the pdf and copy/paste it into a text file to see what sort of text can even be extracted.

If you can't get your solution working you'll need to use another package like [Tika](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python).